# Writing in Command Prompt through Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

So my question may be a little wide so I'll narrow it down here, I have been able to develop code that easily opens command prompt. My question is this, through say the IDE Eclipse, if I ran my program their that printed out HELLO!, how could I make it appear on the command prompt WITHOUT!!! actually accessing command prompt and running my code their?

More calarification? I need a line of code or method that when its executed it opens the command prompt and writes hello. Many would say why not have it run to say hello there but thats defeating the purpose of my task. To clarify further, if I was to run this in windows command prompt instead of eclipse, it would still open a new command prompt window and write hello in their acting as the System.out,
THANKS!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, can you be more clear please?

Comment: It is obvious that you're not a native English speaker, so please don't rush your question. The question may seem clear to you, but to us it's ... well, weird.

Comment: You want to run a program from inside of eclipse, but get the output to print to the command line instead of eclipse's console?

Comment: Well I am native english but let me try to rephrase, I wish to have a method/line of code that when executed in eclipse, it opens the command prompt and writes hello in it. I realize that you could easily run your program through command prompt to have it say hello but I want another window to open for it to say hello.

Comment: Any code will be helpful. Even a drawing

Comment: If you're saying you want a GUI instead of cmd, then look into [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), specifically the [dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: The code to open command prompt is this Process p; p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd");

Comment: @user2966385 He wants to execute program from eclipse. CMD is just for display

Comment: I am actually not that fond of GUI and stick to anything but that for now, just enjoying trying unusual creative ways.

Comment: I think he wants to change STDOUT to the command prompt.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? Seems somewhat silly if it's for a testing scenario.

Comment: I am creating somewhat of a game that involves the creation of a certain number of command prompts and to print different things on each one or even the same. Think of it as 3 command prompts labeled A, B, and C. I for short would want A to the print out of Hello, B would have the print on it of Welcome, and C would have the print of Goodbye. Like I said its more complicated but mostly for fun.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't recommend this, just answering the question

You'd have to run Java in each console with an application that was listening for data from the controlling application (not going to get into how that communication could work, but sockets would be an obvious choice).

The listening application could then write to the console when it receives data from the controlling application - more trouble than it's worth imho

Comment: Yes, you'd be better to capture any output and writing it into a Swing `JTextArea`